# IMDB Etiquette: Can you just claim your role?

Tags: credits

Do you have to have producer permission or lead mixer permission to apply for IMDB credit?  Now that I am freelance I have actually been quite busy on some nice shows and want to list my contributions but I do not want to step on any toes.  Do I just apply honestly to IMDB and describe my role or do I ask each client/supervising sound editor/lead mixer if they mind if I list my role in the production?

Comment: your role and credit on the project should be specified in your contract/deal memo

Answer (score 4):

Same here, I just add myself. I have no idea if the credit is checked with anyone or not.

Answer (score 3):

i believe if you were in the credits, then your are entitled to a credit on imdb. so then just update it yourself and it will be ok'd with the producer before it goes up.

but you can be credited on imdb if you weren't in the end credit but the producer or whoever is in charge of the imdb page will have to put it up.

Comment: and the credit will say "uncredited"

Answer (score 2):

I just go in and list myself on imdb. I don't think that's bad etiquette if you did work on it, and i imagine that everyone does the same. One of my imdb credits is even listed as "uncredited", despite the fact that the post supervisor asked me 2 or 3 times for the spelling of my name for the credits.

Answer (score 1):

I just update my own as well.  I prefer to do so after the show is wrapped (or when I've fully delivered the show and it's finishing out through predubs), because at that point I feel I've properly 'earned' the credit and my work is essentially done.

But that being said, I always get the credit situation sorted out when the show drops and the contract is arranged - I just hold off on posting it.

For my own in-house work I have a line item in my contracts which covers the credit arrangement so we're all on the same page from the start.